# how many points are necessary to determine a cube in 3 dimensions

Tags: euclidean-geometry, 3d

If you have 2 points in 3D, there is only one line passing through them, but infinite planes can pass through them.

If you have 3 points, only one plane can pass through all 3, but infinitely many cubes can have that plane as a side.

how many points do you need to determine a cube?

I guess it is 4, and that feels related to quaternions, but I really don't know.

Comment: A cube can be fully defined from 2 unique 3d points. Just take a mixture of their elements to get 8 corner vertices in 3d space.

Comment: @Pixel could you point to a resource that explains this further? I don't really understand how you phrased your comment.

Comment: sorry for the delay. If your cube has sides parallel to the planes $xy, xz, yz$ then two (corner) points suffices to define the whole cube. However, if your cube is oriented in an arbitrary position, then you can still define a cube by two points (the line can define a central line segment / axis about which it spins), but its angle of orientation around that local central axis would need to be defined, so two points and an angle would suffice. Still that's less information than 3 points I suppose :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an answer, but won't fit in a comment:

This question requires us to be quite precise about what it means for some number of points to "determine a cube". It appears that @amd in his answer assumes a definition something like:

> Let $C$ be the "standard cube", that is, $\bigl([0,1]^3\setminus (0,1)^3\bigr) \subseteq \mathbb R^2$.
>
> Let $A$ be some subset of $C$. We define that $A$ "determines the cube" if *for any two similarity transformations $f$ and $g$* it holds that if $f(A)=g(A)$ then $f(C)=g(C)$.

Under this interpretation, amd's answer of three points ("he diagonal across one face and a perpendicular edge at either end of the diagonal") shows that $A$ can be as small as $3$ points, and it's fairly clear that no *smaller* $A$ can work.

[For the parallelepiped case amd alluded to, we would presumably speak about non-degenereate affine transformations instead of similarity transformations].

However, a different interpretation of the question would be

> Say that a set $B\in\mathbb R^3$ "determines a cube" if
>
> 1. There is a similarity transformation $f$ such that $B\subseteq f(C)$, **and**
> 2. For any two similarity transformations $f$ and $g$ with $B\subseteq f(C)$ and $B\subseteq g(C)$, it holds that $f(C)=g(C)$.
>
> What is the smallest $A$ that determines a cube.

In this interpretation, three points are *not* enough -- for any three points there will be an infinity of large cubes that have those three points lying in the middle of one side.

This second question seems more natural to me. It can be rephrased equivalently as

> What is the smallest set $A\subseteq C$ with the property that if $f$ is a similarity transformation with $A\subseteq f(C)$ then $f(C)=C$?

Unfortunately I have no idea where to start *answering* this. Intuitively I think that at least the eight corners of $C$ ought to work as $A$ -- that is, $A=\{0,1\}^3$. If true that would give an upper bound, but it's not clear to me how to prove it. We can't just declare it to be *obvious* because the analogous property in 2D is not true: The four corners of a square do *not* determine a unique square:
[image]

Comment: ok, your second definition seems closer to what I meant, but its a little outside my ken XD. I thought that 3 points could be mistaken to be coplanar, but a 4th point that wasn't coplanar to the first 3 could NOT be mistaken for being so. That is, you can fit a plane into any 3 points, but a 4th point could not fit into that plane unless it was truly coplanar... does that make sense?

Comment: @honestSalami: Beats me -- as I state I don't even have a proof that _eight_ points is enough. On the other hand, I cannot prove either that four points is _too little_; for example it seems at least conceivable that if we take every other corner of a cube (forming the four corners of a regular tetrahedron), then they might determine that cube. It's possible that the problem is hard :-)

Comment: The corners do not suffice, because you can shrink the cube a bit and rotate it while fitting it snugly in the original so the corners are still in contact with the bigger cube surface. So if we want to do better than 8, we need a set that isn't a subset of the corners. CC @honestSalami